# Mock Microsoft Graph API SDK for Java service Integration Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to write integration tests with tests containers for my JAVA service and I want to find a way to mock the SDK calls. Maybe there are any ways to override the URL for requests and use it with the mock server container or smth?
The main idea is to write tests for the service in a separate container running in production mode.
I'm writing tests using Groovy for Java service with Spring-Boot

Comment: Hi @Orbit419, This might be the exact answer but you can please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS) , which states on how to Make API calls using the Microsoft Graph SDKs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a method `setServiceRoot(String url)` in `BaseClient` class used in unit tests of the project. With this method, you can change the address of the API and use MockServer to mock the calls